# repo.sping.io url is down for most times so unable to deploy application usiing spring cloud data flow server

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-dataflow

We are using https://repo.spring.io/libs-release/org/springframework/cloud/stream/app/spring-cloud-stream-app-descriptor/Darwin.SR1/spring-cloud-stream-app-descriptor-Darwin.SR1.rabbit-apps-maven-repo-url.properties

to import all out of box applications for SCDF but due to site unavalabity for most of time we are failing to deploy the streams. So there any way to work around to use different url to install streaming apps in scdf.

Comment: experiencing the same, can't do any builds for gradle dependencies that pull out of repo.spring.io

Answer (score 0):

JFrog is actively trying to resolve the situation. Please follow [@SpringOps](https://twitter.com/springops) in Twitter for updated re: Spring Repo.

In SCDF, however, you could alternatively pull the App URIs from Maven Central. We ship all the applications to Central as well.

For that to work, you'd have to explicitly configure SCDF's Maven configuration to replace the coordinate from "https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot" to "https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/".

Comment: Until Spring Repo comes back up and running, you cannot use the `https://repo.spring.io/ ...` link that you listed above, but you could copy the `maven://` URIs of the apps and register them in SCDF directly as opposed to using the properties file.